# Linux laravel migrate driver not found

Tags: php, linux, laravel, driver, migrate

i have a error when i running php artisan migrate. It shows could not find driver in connection.php and connector.php , any idea to fix it ?[error php artisan migrate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWWXA.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try checking with 127.0.0.1 and check if you have correct db configuration.